# Use Cell Range As Where Values in a Data Connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2010

I am working on a tool in Excel to rapidly validate data updates to a set of databases.

In Sheet 1, I will have the source data, which consists of 5 columns; Column A is the Primary Key. This is delivered as a CSV and copy/pasted into the sheet.

In Sheet 2, I would like to have a data connection to the database machine that filters on the values of Sheet 1, Column A, such that only those Primary Keys in Sheet 1 will be returned and displayed.

I have tried looking at setting Parameters in the Connection Properties dialog, but the button is disabled:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kJVRnbV.png]

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: This is Excel 2010, and this image shows the method I used to create the connection on Sheet 2:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hi0hs5E.png]

EDIT 2: Attempted to use Microsoft Query to create the connection, but it remains disabled.

[image]

Comment: How did you make the connection on Sheet2?  and what version of Excel is this?

Comment: @RBarryYoung EDITED to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add and manage Query Parameters in Excel by using Microsoft Query.  So when you create the Connection, on the "From Other Sources"  button-dropdown, select "From Microsoft Query" instead of "From SQL Server" (or any other source).

Comment: I have created the connection using a Microsoft Query, but the Parameters button remains locked. 

http://i.imgur.com/lQPppqS.png

Comment: Did you edit the query text to add in the question marks("?") for your parameters first?

Comment: After doing this "where code = ?", the Parameters button appears, but it seems that it only allows me to source a parameter from a single cell, rather than a range.

http://i.imgur.com/9EJSV1s.png

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Until very recently, SQL parameters had to be scalar values.  I.E., single numbers, strings or dates, they could not be lists, arrays or any other data structures.  And the new capabilities (to send a table/list as a parameter) is only accessible from ADO.Net, which Excel does not use.  So yes, only single cells can be query parameters, not ranges.

Comment: To do this in Excel, you would have to write an Excel-VBA procedure that would extract all of the key values from the Range and then actually send them all to the database (using one kludgy method or another), so that SQL could compare them and return the matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can add query parameters to a SQL Query as well as Microsoft Queries, just place a `?` in the SQL query and the parameters button will become active, or a dialog will display prompting for data the next time the connection is refreshed.

It looks like multiple parameters would be possible, however I haven't found a working syntax for them yet.